# AVX2 __m256i const* mem_addr in load instructions vs AVX

Tags: c, x86, simd, avx, avx2

I can not load or store with AVX2 intrinsics instructions as I've done in AVX before. No error, just warnings, and it does not perform the load/store instruction at run-time. Other AVX2 instructions work properly but I can not load from memory.

As follows.

AVX:

```
float t[MAX][MAX];
row0 = _mm256_load_ps(&t[i][j]);
_mm256_store_ps(&t[j][i], row0);
```

AVX2:

```
const int32_t a[MAX][MAX]; // I tried int, long, global and local and many other things... 
a0_i =_mm256_stream_load_si256 (&a[0][0]);
mm256_store_si256(&a[0][0], a0_i);
```

So, What is the problem/difference? Is there any idea or solution?

Comment: What you mean by _can not load from memory_ ? Did you checked the alignment of the array on the stack?

Comment: How and where does it fail? At compile or run time? What is the error you observe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the prototype for [_mm256_stream_load_si256](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm256_stream_load_si256):

```
__m256i _mm256_stream_load_si256 (__m256i const* mem_addr);
```

you can see that you need to cast the to the correct type, i.e.:

```
a0_i =_mm256_stream_load_si256 ((__m256i *)&a[0][0]);
                                 ^^^^^^^^^ ^
```

You also forgot to take the address of the first element of the array, and you have a couple of further mistakes in the subsequent store also:

```
_mm256_store_si256((__m256i *)&a[0][0], a0_i);
^                   ^^^^^^^^^
```

Note that when you have this compiling OK, your next problem may be memory alignment at run-time.

Comment: Thank you very much it works now